# Adding ListView items on CheckBox check with different formatting

Tags: android, listview

I'm using a ListActivity with a Checkbox through an ArrayAdapter. 
What I'm trying to do is adding ListView items **dynamically** with a **different layout** (TextView only) when the checkBox gets checked.
Also it should disappear after getting un-checked again too.

```
CheckBox unchecked:

+----------------------+
|  cb -- some text --  |
+----------------------+
|   - new  Heading -   |
+----------------------+
|         etc.         |
+----------------------+

CheckBox checked:

+----------------------+
|  cb -- some text --  |
+----------------------+
|  ---  TextView  ---  |
+----------------------+
|  ---  TextView  ---  |
+----------------------+
|   - new  Heading -   |
+----------------------+
|         etc.         |
+----------------------+
```

What's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this as follows:

```
final CheckBox checkbox = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Perform action on clicks, depending on whether it's now checked
        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {
            ListView lv=v.getParent();
            TextView tv1=new TextView(this);
            lv.addView(tv1,1);
            TextView tv2=new TextView(this);
            lv.addView(tv2,2);
        } else {
            ListView lv=v.getParent();
            TextView tv1=lv.getChildAt(1);
            TextView tv2=lv.getChildAt(2);

            if(tv1!=null && tv2!=null) lv.removeViews(1, 2);
        }
    }
});
```

Another simplar approach is to define the TextViews from the begining and let the checkbox set their visibility instead.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer! I've found what I've been looking for in the preference:dependency though.